# Issue with post callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a strange behavior of the following code:

```
// Log in the user if credentials are correct
function login() {

    $.post("http://localhost/auth/login", {

        username    : $("#modal-login-username").val(),
        password    : $("#modal-login-password").val(),
        autoLogin   : autoLogin,
        _token      : $("#modal-login-token").val()
    }, 
    function(result) {

        console.log("1"); // This is not printed
        if(result === "OK") {

            window.location.href = "http://localhost/home";
        } else {

            console.log("2"); // This is not printed
            $("#modal-login-message-error").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
    console.log("3"); // This is printed
};
```

In this function I check if the PHP script that logs in the user returns 'OK' or not. If the authentication is successful the user is correctly redirected to `http://localhost/home` but if something goes wrong an `ERROR` string with `500` status is returned but the else statement is not executed.

Comment: Open your console and head to the network tab, is the request going thru?

Comment: Try adding the `.fail`. Your else will only be called when your post is successful.

Comment: Yes, and I also receive a response: `ERROR` with the 500 status, as I programmed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That callback function only gets called on suucess. You can place your call in the .always() method of post:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php")
.always(function() {
    console.log("1"); // This is not printed
    if(result === "OK") {

        window.location.href = "http://localhost/home";
    } else {

        console.log("2"); // This is not printed
        $("#modal-login-message-error").removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

for more details have a look at the jQuery page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

or even better:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/home";
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("2"); // This is not printed
    $("#modal-login-message-error").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: +1 for mention of .always(), think a separate .fail would be better though. (but you have a typo in success). Ah, you agree, excellent :)

Comment: @valanto This works only with POST requests? Can I handle in the same way also GET requests?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(...).fail(function () {
    //handle failure here
});
```